# Google doesn't use meta description on SERP

Tags: seo, google-search, search-results, meta-description

We changed the sites UI, CMS, link structure. Also Bought a new and better domain name. After we completed everything. We did below step by step;

1. Created a new web application for old.com/page1.html to new.com/page1.html 301 redirection.
2. Used webmmaster tools for 301 redirection.
3. Sent new sitemaps a long with robots.txt

Although we've got a custom title,meta descrpition and meta keywords for every page, Google takes a piece of sentece from content and uses it for MetaDescription. This is a big problem for our potential clicks on SERP. What should we do for getting back MetaDescription?

The old site is : indirimkodlari.gen.tr

The new site : indirimkodu.gen.tr

Google still shows the old url and right meta description with it.

[image]

The new domain name with randomly scraped on Google search of site.com/url

[image]

**Solution**
Looking at Google's search cache by using "view source" shows we used the wrong field from database for MetaDescription! Changed it, fixed, and solved!.

Comment: The use of the description meta tag is highly dependent upon the search query. What search queries are you using?

Comment: If Google consider the new domain name as old domain names child, it suppose to use meta description as it was.

Comment: No. Not at all. What Google shows as a SERP snippet depends upon the search query. It has nothing to do with domain names and which one is new or not. It all comes down to the search query. It is one of the very last steps before rendering the SERPs.

Comment: I do understand your logic, however, how search works, this logic does not make sense. These are two different domains and you simply cannot conflate one with the other even when it seems to make sense. Each will perform differently especially while the links and 301 redirects work themselves out.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have done all required with regards to move.

Now, in relation to meta description, as written in the comment, Google more often generates meta title and description based on the search query.

> This is a big problem for our potential clicks on SERP.

If this is a problem, meaning if you are not happy with how Google generates (content) meta description then first you should work on your website content to make it more relevant based on your ideas what user may type and then when Google will pickup the content from your description, it may be more relevant from your side.

Also, note that if you optimise your page for specific keywords and if your custom meta title and description will be based on that then mostly likely you will see your custome meta tags.

Comment: Before we move to other domain permanantly it was okay. Google was showing the right content  MetaDescription field which comes from database. Also the content seems very good because our positions were really good. Mostly site was in top ten

Comment: Firstly, not matter what you do, you may not be able to control 100%. Meaning you don't know what user will type and Google will pick the best for the user from your website content. Now, to answer your question regarding it was OK in your old site, you need to understand that since you changed the website (UI, coding structure etc) its not same anymore.  Meaning, you should stop worrying for something which you can't control. But you may like to try my last line in the answer, it has always worked.

Comment: You are perfectly right on this. One set of metrics are the clues given by links that do not exist for the new domain except for any redirect. This will simply take quite a while to work out. Also consider SERP performance history. The OP should guage search queries from the old domain and sculpt a meta description per page to capture as many search terms that make sense. As well, the OP can use the site: directive to make sure there not a real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to Fetch and render the page inside Google Search Console? When you do that you can also ask Google to index the page.
Sometimes the changes are visible just a few moments after but most often you need to wait a day or two.
Also, it's not uncommon for Google to split test their own title/meta descriptions the the search results to see if they can find a better version than what you have come up with. If not, you will get your own description back.. eventually.

Also, use a tool to verify that your meta description actually is working. You can use the tool Screaming frog or the Chrome browser extension SEOquake to check.

Comment: We used fetch and render after we done 301 on GWMT.

I've installed SEOquake plugin to check. It seems all good. SEOquake  shows it fully true.  But Google still uses the first paragraf from page.


Site is : [https://indirimkodu.gen.tr/boyner](https://indirimkodu.gen.tr/boyner) 


Am I missing something else?